# Pandas: Divide two rows by each other

Tags: python, pandas

Here are two rows from my data frame:

```
>>> test.loc[test.index.year == 2009]
                     0         1           2           3           4  \
date                                                                   
2009-01-01  252.855283  353.6261  556.295659  439.558188  432.936844   

                     5           6  employment  
date                                            
2009-01-01  439.437132  433.269903   64.116667 

>>> test.loc[test.index.year == 2007]
                     0           1           2           3           4  \
date                                                                     
2007-01-01  269.277757  380.608002  401.765546  491.893821  433.864499   

                     5           6  employment  
date                                            
2007-01-01  492.396073  489.260588     69.1375
```

When I tried `divide`, I got

```
>>> test.loc[test.index.year == 2009].divide(test.loc[test.index.year == 2007])
             0   1   2   3   4   5   6  employment
date                                              
2007-01-01 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN         NaN
2009-01-01 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN         NaN
```

Which comes from `pandas` trying to divide columns comparing the index. However, none of the options in `axis=` helped me. I could get the correct result doing

```
test.loc[test.index.year == 2009].values / test.loc[test.index.year == 2007].values
array([[ 0.93901288,  0.92910842,  1.38462759,  0.8936038 ,  0.99786188,
         0.89244646,  0.88556061,  0.92737902]])
```

Is there no better way of doing this? I would like to keep the index `2007-01-01` corresponding to the record - of course, I could reattach it to the values, but usually when I was trying to do these kind of things there was my way, and then there was the right way. So: What else could I do?

Comment: Doesn't just `test.loc[test.index.year == 2009]/test.loc[test.index.year == 2007]` work?

Comment: @EdChum: No, that gives me the same as `divide()`

Comment: ```test.div(test.shift())``` will definitely work for this but may or may not be convenient depending on what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: This is a bug to me, your index is of dtype datetimeindex, when perform loc and trying to divide it produces NaN, if you did this then it would work `df.iloc[3]/df.iloc[5]` and produce the correct result. So you can either reset the index and find the row with that value and perform the division or try to use the integer index value to select that row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to keep the index for 2007, I think you can just do:

```
df.loc[df.index.year == 2007]/df.loc[df.index.year == 2009].values
```

The reason why `df.loc[df.index.year == 2007]/df.loc[df.index.year == 2009]` or `df.loc[df.index.year == 2007].divide(df.loc[df.index.year == 2009])` are not working is that `pandas` tries to align the data by their index. In this case, what will happen is data for 2007 will be divided by data with index value of 2007 (same applies for 2009). That's why you are getting, 2, not just 1 row of `Nan`s.

Therefore we need to cast one of them into they respective `np.array` in order to get this working. (`df.loc[df.index.year == 2007]/df.loc[df.index.year == 2009].values`). The index of the numerator, since it is untouched, is retained.

@EdChum, I don't think it is a bug, I think it is the intended behavior for boolean indexing, considering this:

```
df.iloc[df.index.year>=2007]/df.loc[df.index.year == 2007]
             0   1   2   3   4   5   6  employment
date                                              
2007-01-01   1   1   1   1   1   1   1           1
2009-01-01 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN         NaN
```

But you should be careful about this approach, because you may get more than one row from boolean indexing, see these two examples:

```
In [128]:

print df
                     0           1           2           3           4  \
2007-12-31  252.855283  353.626100  556.295659  439.558188  432.936844   
2008-12-31  269.277757  380.608002  401.765546  491.893821  433.864499   
2009-12-31  269.277757  380.608002  401.765546  491.893821  433.864499   

                     5           6          7  
2007-12-31  439.437132  433.269903  64.116667  
2008-12-31  492.396073  489.260588  69.137500  
2009-12-31  492.396073  489.260588  69.137500  
In [130]:

print df.iloc[df.index.year==2007]/df.loc[df.index.year >= 2007]
#divide one row by 3 rows? Dimension mismatch? No, it will work just fine.
             0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7
2007-12-31   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
2008-12-31 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2009-12-31 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
In [131]:

df.iloc[df.index.year==2007]/df.loc[df.index.year >= 2007].values
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
**************
ValueError: Shape of passed values is (8, 3), indices imply (8, 1)
#basically won't work due to dimension mismatch
```

Comment: But in that example you are explicitly selecting multiple values, here we select single row values for the division, the naive assumption would be that this would perform a simple division, I guess it's unexpected but designed behaviour

Comment: My guess is, it is potentially possible that boolean indexing *may* return more than one row, instead of explicit index such as `df.iloc[3]/df.iloc[5]`, which will *only* return single row. If this is the designers' intention, I think it makes better sense to have two different behavior. But anyway, it is their call... The OP's approach may still be dangerous anyway, see edit.

Comment: I've +1 ed everyone's contribution to this, I think you are correct and it makes sense, it's one of those subtle things that doesn't tend to bite you when using unique int indexes and selecting rows using `loc`

Comment: can you please have a look at my question [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62083576/pandas-row-filters-and-and-division-from-specific-rows-and-columns]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps:

```
test = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,5), index=[pd.Timestamp('2007-01-01'), pd.Timestamp('2008-01-01')])

>>> test.loc[test.index.year == 2007].divide(test.loc[test.index.year == 2008].values)
               0         1         2         3         4
2007-01-01  0.496822 -1.198635  0.222452  0.688838  0.256559
```

Comment: The OP has already stated that they've tried that and it works

Comment: @EdChum  -- it's different, Alexander only used ```values``` on the second part whereas FooBar used on both.  Hence, Alexander's way keeps it as a Series/DataFrame.  He should have showed the output and it would have been more obvious.

Comment: Fair enough didn't spot that but I think this is a bug as it works if the dtype of the index is Int64 or if you use `iloc`